# Bootstrap modal - close effect missing

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I am using the bootstrap modals with modal.js and instead of including the whole bootstrap.css I have only imported the needed classes:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
  transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
       -o-transition:      -o-transform .3s ease-out;
          transition:         transform .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
       -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
          transform: translate(0, -25%);
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
.modal-header {
  min-height: 16.42857143px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.modal-footer .btn + .btn {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-group .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-block + .btn-block {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.modal-scrollbar-measure {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

The problem is, I am missing the fade effect when closing the modals and I cannot figure out what class is being used.
When I close a modal it just disappear straight away without any fade effect.

Can anyone help?

This is the example on JSFiddle:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ec4beebx/)

Thank you

Comment: can you share a working example?

Comment: Why would you not include all of bootstrap? You don't need to really care about the performance here, since the compressed CSS has minimal impact and saves you from many problems later on (like this one).

Comment: @Andrew I have added a working example. Thanks!

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak It's because I really don't want to include tons of CSS that I am not using and that may potentially create issues with my existing website...

Comment: @Andrew I have just found the solution to the problem, see below if you are interested. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution can be to include the whole Bootstrap file and use "uncss" at the end.

Comment: Interesting, do you know if uncss is available for grunt?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer to the problem.
The modal.js class requires transitions.js in order to use the closing fade effect.
See below "$.support.transition..."

```
  Modal.prototype.hide = function (e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault()

    e = $.Event('hide.bs.modal')

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.isShown = false

    this.escape()
    this.resize()

    $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal')

    this.$element
      .removeClass('in')
      .off('click.dismiss.bs.modal')
      .off('mouseup.dismiss.bs.modal')

    this.$dialog.off('mousedown.dismiss.bs.modal')

    $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
      this.$element
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(this.hideModal, this))
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Modal.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
      this.hideModal()
  }
```

Including this file solved the problem.